# Automating Java Code Writing

Tags: java

We have an application where in we are using technologies like Java, Elastic Search, EXT JS. We very often face the requirement of adding a new field in our application which inturn means adding that field in multiple java classes. But the process remains the same for all the fields which need to be added newly and hence making it tedious. Can I write an utility in java using which based on certain inputs like class name, field name and some other specific details the code will be auto generated in the required java files? Please suggest the feasibility

Comment: If you have such requirement why don't you store all the fields in a database table and render them dynamically instead of changing the source code everytime?

Comment: give a example..

Comment: Look at autovalue - https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @BackSlash: The code has been written in such a way. So storing them in database would mean changing the ancient base code a lot which isn't possible considering the stringent timelines. Hence I would looking for more options.

Comment: Simple answer: yes, it is feasible. Longer answer: its feasibility depends on how long you're willing to invest. It's easy if the code is well-structured already; not so otherwise. It is possible that just putting your head down and editing the classes manually is most expedient.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can write the code which will generate the Java Code. There are multiple options to do this kind of operation like
1. List down all field in one of the file in CSV. 
2. Your utility will read this file and generate similar kind of .java file.
Here, a utility has to do a lot of string operation which requires executing your code.
3. Finally, your utility will replace existing classes with newly generated classes.

I will not suggest you to manually edit the Java file as it will make process complex.